# Guice: module testing

Tags: java, tdd, guice

I want to test my Guice modules and I managed to do it for modules containing bindings only.
Now I'm wondering how to test this kind of module?

```
class ModuleA extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected voir configure() {
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), new ModuleAProperties());
        install(new ModuleB());
    }
}
```

1. How to test bindProperties()?
2. How to test install()?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448013/how-test-guice-injections

Answer (score 4):

Since guice is the framework you are using, you certainly dont want to test install() or bindProperties(). You are interested in the result of those operations.

So create a Test, create an injector in the @Before method and then test what values/instances you get with your module configuration.