# Guice, DI, and Unit Tests in Play 2.4

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice, playframework-2.4

So I've been trying to figure this out on my own via documentation but I'm not getting anywhere.

I've got some simple DI bindings setup in a service class that creates a repository object. Simple. However, when I run this in test mode, @Inject does nothing and the repository object is never instantiated.

```
@Inject
TagRepository tagRepository;
```

So on the line where it's use, in test mode, we of course get a NullPointerException

```
tagRepository.tagExistsByName(tag);
```

This bubbles up into my test like so:

```
[error] Test services.TagsServiceTest.testAddNewTag failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null, took 0.097 sec
[error]     at services.TagService.tagExists(TagService.java:27)
[error]     at services.TagService.addNewTag(TagService.java:18)
[error]     at services.TagsServiceTest.testAddNewTag(TagsServiceTest.java:29)
```

My question is, how do I configure my application to use Guice injectors in test mode? I didn't have this problem with my controllers because requests were actually being made to them, setting up the full application.

One thing I should mention is that I'm using a provider to provide my app to the tests. Should I be using the Guice application builder? If so, where does that go? The play docs aren't very helpful in that regard. Here is the provider

```
@Override
protected FakeApplication provideFakeApplication() {
    return new FakeApplication(new java.io.File("."), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), ImmutableMap.of("play.http.router", "router.Routes"), new ArrayList<String>(), null);
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the update based on the suggestion below

Inside my BaseTest class

```
    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.TEST).build();
    }
```

And then in the service testing class

```
    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        Injector injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder().bindings(bind(TagService.class).toInstance(new TagService())).injector();
        tagService = injector.instanceOf(TagService.class);
    }
```

However, I'm still getting null pointer exceptions because the TagRepository isn't being injected.

ANSWER:

I was thinking about this slightly wrong. If you setup the injector with the object you need to inject, then create an instance from that, you won't get any more NullPointerExceptions

```
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    Injector injector = new GuiceInjectorBuilder().bindings(bind(TagRepository.class).toInstance(new TagRepository())).injector();
    tagService = injector.instanceOf(TagService.class);
}
```

Comment: I think that you forget to create the mock of the `@Injected` repository and that's why you get the exception.

Comment: What would the proper way to create that mock be? Application builder? If so, where would that go?

Comment: If you are using constructor or parameter injection it would be fairly easy but from what you have you provided I am guessing you are not using any of them so take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448013/how-test-guice-injections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're extending `WithApplication`, you can override `protected Application provideApplication()` to return an `Application` built using `GuiceApplicationBuilder`.

For example (based on [this code](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/AbstractFakeApplicationTest.java)) you can create your app, add or override bindings, etc, and set the mode.  If you make the class abstract, it will then work automatically with all child classes.

```
public abstract class AbstractFakeApplicationTest extends WithApplication
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractFakeApplicationTest.class);

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication()
    {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(Mode.TEST)
                                            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void startPlay()
    {
        super.startPlay();
        // mock or otherwise provide a context
        Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context(1L,
                                                  Mockito.mock(RequestHeader.class),
                                                  Mockito.mock(Http.Request.class),
                                                  Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                                                  Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                                                  Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap()));
    }

    public Http.Context context()
    {
        return Http.Context.current.get();
    }
}
```

Child classes then just extend this class and test as normal - all DI should occur as it does when you run the app normally.

You can see various examples of it [here](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/tree/master/code/test/be/objectify/deadbolt/java)

This gives the basic outline for what you need to do.  Hopefully the docs at https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWithGuice will make a bit more sense now.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I'll give it a shot tonight and see what happens

Comment: I tried this and it's still throwing NullPointerException's. Pasted my code in my question. I followed the examples you gave me, and meshed that up with what's on the Play docs, but I still can't get the injector to work right.

Comment: Never mind, figured out that I have to bind the injected repository object to the Injector, then create a TagService object from that. You pointed me down the right path, thanks so much!